# Elasticsearch Query aggregated by unique substrings (email domain)

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an elasticsearch query that queries over an index and then aggregates based on a specific field `sender_not_analyzed`. I then use a term aggregation on that same field `sender_not_analyzed` which returns buckets for the top "senders". My query is currently:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "regexp": {
         "sender_not_analyzed": ".*[@].*"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "sender-stats": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "sender_not_analyzed"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns buckets that look like:

```
"aggregations": {
      "sender-stats": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "<Mike <mike@fizzbuzz.com>@MISSING_DOMAIN>",
               "doc_count": 5017
            },
            {
               "key": "jon.doe@foo.com",
               "doc_count": 3963
            },
            {
               "key": "jane.doe@foo.com",
               "doc_count": 2857
            },
            {
              "key": "jon.doe@bar.com",
              "doc_count":1544
            }
```

How can I write an aggregation such that I get single bucket for each unique email domain, eg `foo.com` would have a `doc_count` of (3963 + 2857) 6820? Can I accomplish this with a regex aggregation or do I need to write some kind of custom analyzer to split the string at the @ to the end of string?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty late, but I think this can be done by using [pattern_replace char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html), you capture the domain name with `regex`, This is my setup

```
POST email_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "domain"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "domain": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": ".*@(.*)",
          "replacement": "$1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "domain": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
        },
        "sender_not_analyzed": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "copy_to": "domain"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here `domain char filter` will capture the domain name, we need to use [keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) to get the domain as it is, I am using `lowercase` filter but it is up to you if you want to use it or not. Using [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) parameter to copy the value of the `sender_not_analyzed` to `domain` field, although `_source` field won't be modified to include this value but we can query it.

```
GET email_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "sender_not_analyzed": ".*[@].*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sender-stats": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "domain"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you desired result.