# Aggregation for similar strings

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have similar strings that I want to aggregate, 
but they seem to be different within few characters at the end.

for example:

```
doc1: {"message":"hello world and good morning1 300"} 
doc2: {"message":"hello world and good morning1 200"} 
doc3: {"message":"hello world and good morning1 100"}
```

I would like to have this result in the aggregation:

```
"hello world and good morning1" - count: 3
```

the field currently defined with default analyzer

btw, is it possible to identify also more complicated string such as:

```
doc3: {"message":"500 hello world and good morning1 100"}
```

thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**

the actually data is urls:
and example can be:  "www.domain.com/a/b/c/123456-d-sadf-asdf/collect", and "www.domain.com/a/b/c/pio-rddddd-fffff/collect", where we want that the result would be:  www.domain.com/a/b/c/*/collect. meaning to count all the "non meaningful" urls to 1 meaningful.

Lior

Comment: Where is your "message" coming from? If you're looking to compute all word combinations in a substring, you're looking at a very expensive operation. But if you can tokenise your message upstream (e.g. feeding it through `logstash` or similar) then it becomes pretty easy.

Comment: can you explain please "But if you can tokenise your message upstream" ? example maybe?

Comment: Depends entirely on what's inserting your documents into elasticsearch.

Comment: in house ETL -  java application

Comment: OK. So if it's a consistent pattern, then get that app to amend what it's sending (regex your message into separate fields).

Comment: the patterns is not consistent. it can be new pattern each time

Comment: can you add info about how would logstash help here?

Comment: do you know that **particular similar string**? is it always `hello world and good morning1`?

Comment: no. the actually data is urls:
and example can be:  "www.domain.com/a/b/c/123456-d-sadf-asdf/collect", and "www.domain.com/a/b/c/pio-rddddd-fffff/collect", where we want that the result would be:  www.domain.com/a/b/c/*/collect. meaning to count all the "non meaningful" urls to 1 meaningful.

Comment: I have answered something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156983/elasticsearch-query-aggregated-by-unique-substrings-email-domain/34378552#34378552), I guess your only option seems to be pattern char filter. Does this help? also please refer to so users with @ so that we can get notification

Comment: Hi @ChintanShah25, I'm not sure because my case is harder (I think): the urls i get belongs to many websites, and I don't know their structure. I was hoping that elasticsearch will help me to find similar urls, so i can count them as one